# How can I pull data from an excel spreadsheet and compare it to a field in powerapps?

Tags: excel, powerapps

I am trying to make a login system for a powerapps project I have and I want to be able to pull data from my excel spreadsheet and compare it to what inside the field the user entered.

I am currently able to insert data from the powerapps into the excel spreadsheet but cant find out how to pull data and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your Excel spreadsheet is a datasource in your PowerApps application, so you can use formulas like "LookUp" to filter your datasource a compare datas from your app :

```
LookUp([Your Excel data source], [Your column to compare] = [Your user field].Text)
```

Please refere to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) for more informations

Have a good day